# Как получить адрес абсолютный адрес к файлу стилей через PHP?

Tags: php

Есть страница: `http://project/dev/works/site/`.

В папке `dev` лежит папка `styles`.

На странице путь к стилям прописан относительно: `../../../styles/styles.css`, и открывается по адресу `http://project/styles/styles.css`.

Возможно ли через PHP получить абсолютный путь к этому файлу, чтобы его прочитать?

Comment: Вообще страница эта: http://mhelper.ru/project/dev/works/ElenaBeauty/index.html
И нужно как-то через php получить абсолютные адреса файлов стилей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписанная js-функция, взятая из англоязычного [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14780463/9908035).

```
function absolute_path($base, $relative)
{
    list($stack, $parts) = [explode('/', $base), explode('/', $relative)];
    array_pop($stack);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++)
    {
        if ($parts[$i] == '')
            continue;
        elseif ($parts[$i] == '..')
            array_pop($stack);
        else
            array_push($stack, $parts[$i]);
    }

    return join('/', $stack);
}
```

Пробуем и получаемый нужный результат.

```
echo absolute_path(
    'http://mhelper.ru/project/dev/works/ElenaBeauty/index.html', '../../css/reset.css'
);
```

https://3v4l.org/DRPcB

Comment: Не совсем понял, нужный результат был бы, если бы получили http://project/styles/styles.css

Comment: С чего вы решили, что результат будет такой? http://mhelper.ru/project/styles/styles.css - такой страницы нет.

Comment: http://mhelper.ru/project/styles/owl.carousel.css, она там тоже абсолютно указана. Эта функция не справится

Comment: @Frontender, правда? https://3v4l.org/GfMbB

Comment: в пхп своих функций что ли нет, чтобы с js переписывать?

Comment: извиняюсь, все верно :-)

Comment: @teran, мне этот вариант показался интересным, можете предоставить на пхп ответ)